# esbuild throws error on iOS older version which related to private methods

Tags: typescript, webpack, esbuild

I recently changed esbuild to speed up the build time. However, it seems to throw an error on the old version of the iOS. The error shows

In chrome

> unexpected private name #s cannot parse class method with private name

In Safari

> Syntax Error: invalid character ‘#’

I targeted es2015 to not break old ones. Has anyone had this issue?
Someone suggested mingle props but it does not seem to work.

```
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },

}
```

Comment: ES2015 is equivalent to ES6, not ES5. In any case, you've tagged this question with TypeScript, which should do the transpilation to ES5 on its own, before esbuild even gets involved. [Edit] your question to show what's in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: updated some stuff @HereticMonkey

Comment: You're combining a number of options that are not really mean to be used together. If you are targeting es5, you probably shouldn't include the esnext lib, for example. You also probably don't want to use esnext for module either, since modules came out in es6/es2015. If you have to support es5, you have to forgo modules. I'm guessing that mixing the esnext stuff with a target of es5 is causing TS to emit some odd JavaScript. I'd look at the JS output to see what's wrong with that.

Comment: I tried to replace esnext to es2015. The result is same.